# Shared Column Headers in XamDataGrid via GUI at runtime

Tags: wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

How does the user change the columns in a XamDataGrid such that it sets the ColumnSpan and/or RowSpan properties?  I know how to do this programatically, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it via the keyboard and mouse at runtime.  Are there any options I need to set on the grid in order for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

By default this isn't supported in the XamDataGrid.  Doing this programmatically is the only way to achieve this so if you have some mechanism in place to change these programmatically during runtime then you can do it but it's something you'll need to write yourself.

This does sound like a very useful feature though so you should head on over to the Infragistics site and submit a feature request for this.
https://www.infragistics.com/my-account/feature-request/